# Jquery numeric keypad input issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to put a comma "," in a javascript numeric keypad.  see code below

```
 /*!
* JQFNumKeypad
* http://www.jqueryfun.com/
*/
(function($) {
  $.fn.JQFNumKeypad = function(options) {

    // Defaults
    var defaults = {
      fadeSpeed: 400,
      clearText: 'Clear'
    };

    // Extend options
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    // Show keypad on document click / Focus First
    $(document).click(function() {$('.jqfnumkeypad').show();});
    $(document).ready(function(){$('input').first().focus();});

    // Loop each instance
    return this.each(function() {

      // Instance
      var instance = $(this);

      // Keypad layout
      var keypad = '<div id="jqfnumkeypad_' + instance.attr('name') + '" class="jqfnumkeypad"><div class="jqfnumkeypad_keypad"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
      for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if((i-1)%3 == 0) keypad += '<tr>';
        keypad += '<td class="jqfnumkeypad_digit">' + i + '</td>';
        if(i%3 == 0) keypad += '</tr>';
      }
      keypad += '<tr><td class="jqfnumkeypad_digit">0</td><td class="jqfnumkeypad_clear">' + options.clearText + '</td><td class="jqfnumkeypad_coma">,</td></tr></table></div></div>';
      $(keypad).insertAfter(instance).css({right: 0, top: instance.position().top});

      // Prevent hide on click
      instance.click(function(e) {e.stopPropagation();});

      // Define on focus event
      instance.focus(function() {
        $('#jqfnumkeypad_' + instance.attr('name')).css('z-index', '99').fadeIn(options.fadeSpeed, function() {
          // Digit click
          $('#jqfnumkeypad_' + instance.attr('name') + ' .jqfnumkeypad_digit').unbind().bind('click', function(e) {
          if(instance.attr('maxlength') == -1 || instance.val().length < instance.attr('maxlength')) instance.val(instance.val() + parseFloat($(this).html()));
            e.stopPropagation();
          });
          // Clear click
          $('#jqfnumkeypad_' + instance.attr('name') + ' .jqfnumkeypad_clear').unbind().bind('click', function(e) {
            instance.val('');
            e.stopPropagation();
          });
          // Coma click
          $('#jqfnumkeypad_' + instance.attr('name') + ' .jqfnumkeypad_coma').unbind().bind('click', function(e) {
            if(instance.attr('maxlength') == -1 || instance.val().length < instance.attr('maxlength')) instance.val(instance.val() + $(this).html());
            e.stopPropagation();
          });

        }).siblings('div').css('z-index', '0');
        // Blur to prevent instance events
        instance.blur();
      });
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Can anyone help me fix the issue? 
currently when you press the comma button, it clears the input field.
I need the comma since the input needed is on follows the european currency format

Comment: What have you tried in terms of debugging? When you click the comma, is the click event handler for it called? If yes, what is the value returned by `instance.attr('maxlength')`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Masked Input plugin for jQuery on the input field: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

This way you don't have to have your users input the `,` and you still get the format you want.